# Ionic 2 page gets pushed two times on notification

Tags: angular, push-notification, ionic2

I have a situation when I need to push a specific page on an Ionic 2 app when a notification is received. The behavior of the app is correct but the page gets pushed two times (a bug that I noticed even in the Twitter iOS app). Can someone please point any errors in the code pasted below? Thanks!

```js
push.on('notification', function(data) {
  let offer = JSON.parse(data.additionalData.offer);
  this.app.getActiveNav().push(OfferDetailsPage, {
    currentOffer: offer,
    displayArrow: true
  });
  // Propagate new event to load the new offer
  events.publish('offer:new', offer, Date.now());
});
```

**Edit:** Also the container of the pages is a Tabs page.

Comment: `function(data {` you may have a typo here

Comment: thank you for your point but it is only a typo that I made during the writing of the question, the problem still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem. When iOS receives a notification using phonegap-plugin-push and the application is in background it gets processed two times: one when receiving it and the second time when the user clicks on the notification. A suggestion for everyone who faces this problem: assign a random ID to your notifications on the server and when the front-end receives it process the notification only if this ID does not exist in storage.

Answer (score 0):

What does the function initiated by the event 'offer:new' ?

Have you checked with logs that the notification event is not triggered 2 times?

Comment: It only triggers an event at the corresponding page to reload data from the server